# How to use google python oauth libraries to implement OpenID Connect?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-oauth, openid-connect

I am evaluating different options for authentication in a python App Engine flex environment, for apps that run within a G Suite domain.

I am trying to put together the OpenID Connect "Server flow" instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect) with how [google-auth-library-python](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python) implements the general OAuth2 instructions [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer).

I kind of follow things up until **4. Exchange code for access token and ID token**, which looks like `flow.fetch_token`, except it says "response to this request contains the following fields in a JSON array," and it includes not just the access token but the id token and other things. I did see [this patch to the library](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python/pull/234). Does that mean I could use some `flow.fetch_token` to create an `IDTokenCredentials` (how?)  and then use this to build an OpenID Connect API client (and where is that API documented)?  And what about validating the id token, is there a separate python library to help with that or is that part of the API library?

It is all very confusing. A great deal would be cleared up with some actual "soup to nuts" example code but I haven't found anything anywhere on the internet, which makes me think (a) perhaps this is not a viable way to do authentication, or (b) it is so recent the python libraries have not caught up?  I would however much rather do authentication on the server than in the client with Google Sign-In.

Any suggestions or links to code are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Google's python library contains a module for id token validation. This can be found at [google.oauth2.id_token module](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.id_token.html#module-google.oauth2.id_token). Once validated, it will return the decoded token which you can use to obtain user information.

```
from google.oauth2 import id_token
from google.auth.transport import requests

request = requests.Request()

id_info = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(
    token, request, 'my-client-id.example.com')

if id_info['iss'] != 'https://accounts.google.com':
    raise ValueError('Wrong issuer.')

userid = id_info['sub']
```

Once you obtain user information, you should follow authentication process as described in [Authenticate the user section](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#authuser).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, poking around a little more I did see that (and code for how to cache the certificates). The other half of the question is how to make the token request to get the id token in the first place, in the midst of a web app flow.  Perhaps this has to be done manually at this point?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I think I found my answer in the source code now.

[`google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python/blob/master/google/oauth2/credentials.py) exposes `id_token`:

> Depending on the authorization server and the scopes requested, this may be populated when credentials are obtained and updated when `refresh` is called. This token is a JWT. It can be verified and decoded [as @kavindu-dodanduwa pointed out] using `google.oauth2.id_token.verify_oauth2_token`.

And [several layers down the call stack](https://github.com/oauthlib/oauthlib/blob/master/oauthlib/oauth2/rfc6749/parameters.py) we can see `fetch_token` does some minimal validation of the response JSON (checking that an access token was returned, etc.) but basically passes through whatever it gets from the token endpoint, including (i.e. if an OpenID Connect scope is included) the id token as a JWT.

EDIT:

And the final piece of the puzzle is the translation of tokens from the (generic) OAuthSession to (Google-specific) credentials in [google_auth_oauthlib.helpers](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-auth-library-python-oauthlib/blob/master/google_auth_oauthlib/helpers.py), where the `id_token` is grabbed, if it exists.

Note that [the generic oauthlib library does seem to implement OpenID Connect now](https://github.com/oauthlib/oauthlib/tree/master/oauthlib/openid/connect), but looks to be very recent and in process (July 2018). Google doesn't seem to use any of this at the moment (this threw me off a bit).